# Two appengine clients with separate databases

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I run two appengine clients (of the same app) with separate databases locally?
What is best practice to achieve this?

Comment: I always have a few versions of eclipse that I can run simultaneously.  Just download eclipse, install it somewhere else, and run them both at once (after installing GAE on #2, of course).  It's one way, probably there are a million ways.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "appengine clients"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `--datastore_path=` [command line argument of the local dev server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments). Change the path to have different databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GAE namespaces.